# Sending DateTime to an API Rest

Tags: c#, datetime, restsharp

Good afternoon,

I'm trying to send a DateTime using RestSharp library doing something like that:

```
RestClient httpClient = new RestClient(APIurl);
RestRequest request = new RestRequest("/Get", Method.POST);
string dateTime = model.fireDiscoveryDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.fffZ");

 request.AddObject(new GetConflictsRequestModel()
            {
                token = model.token,
                f = "json",
                pooLatitude = model.pooLatitude,
                pooLongitude  = model.pooLongitude,
                fireDiscoveryDateTime = dateTime,
                dispatchCenterId  = model.dispatchCenterId
            });
IRestResponse<GetConflictsResponseModel> conflictsResponse = httpClient.Execute<GetConflictsResponseModel>(request);
```

Without fireDiscoveryDateTime I don't have any problem but when I try to parse dateTime to ISO-8601 i have this problem and the content executing the request is the next one:

```
"{\"success\":false,\"error\":{\"code\":8006,\"description\":\"Unable to construct conflict query.\\n\"}}"
```

If I use some program to do post like POSTMAN and I copy&paste all parameters I obtain executing this program I don't have this error and this return what I want :

```
{"conflicts":[]}
```

I dont' know what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Firstly, you want `HH` rather than `hh`. But why are you doing the formatting yourself? I'd expect your request model to have a `DateTime` and get RestSharp to do the formatting for you.

Comment: If I don't format it, the client returns something like "{\"success\":false,\"error\":{\"code\":8004,\"description\":\"\\nfireDiscoveryDateTime: Invalid type. Expected DateTime.\\r\\n\\n\"}}"

Comment: You might consider using the format string `"o"`. The output should be ISO-8601 compliant. Read more about it here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Roundtrip

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly fireDiscoveryDateTime is DateTime and you try to assign a string to it, don't try to parse it and then convert again to datetime and just try this:

```
 request.AddObject(new GetConflictsRequestModel()
            {
                token = model.token,
                f = "json",
                pooLatitude = model.pooLatitude,
                pooLongitude  = model.pooLongitude,
                fireDiscoveryDateTime = model.fireDiscoveryDateTime,
                dispatchCenterId  = model.dispatchCenterId
            });
```